# Archbang linux- error "target not found" trying to install programs

Tags: arch-linux

how to install programs into Archbang ? I get error: no target found
 after trying to install example, sudo pacman -S yaourt
.

Answer (score 0):

yaourt is not in the main repository, you can add it from the AUR or you can configure the

`[archlinuxfr]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch`

to your /etc/pacman.conf file.  pacman -Syy after.